# Убрать цвет кнопки

Tags: java, android

Как убрать стандартный цвет кнопки. Хочу сделать стиль кнопки и создал drawable в котором прописано:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="15dp" />
        </shape>
```

при подключении данного файла через  android:background="@drawable/buttonstyle" цвет не меняется( стандартный фиолетовый цвет всегда). В обычном режиме через    backgroundTint цвет меняется спокойно.

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/calc"
        android:layout_width="326dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonstyle"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/calc" />
```

в итоге если подключать файл то цвет не меняется но закругление применяется, при попытке добавить backgroundTint одновременно с подключенным файлом, ничего не происходит. Подскажите пожалуйста что делать? файл Style у меня нету как сказано в других вопросах, видимо в новой версии данные хранятся  в themes.

Короче не знаю что делать и как заставить его менять цвет( solid в файле тоже пытался применить не подходит)

P.S попытался подключить файл через android:backgroundTint="@drawable/buttonstyle"
файл не подключился а цвет фона стал черным. Короче не знаю че делать. помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решен

в файле themes.xml изменил colorPrimary на свой, теперь первым всегда используется мой цвет. Как обычно все так легко. если покопаться, извините за глупый пост.